# Java - Convert String array to Hash map

Tags: java, regex, arrays, hashmap

I have the following values :

```
1. nickname=Antony###account=4587569854256
2. nickname=^(?![ ])(?=.*[\w]).{1,70}(?<!\s)$###account=^([0-9]{3,20})$
```

I am able to split these strings but how do I put them in to map as key and value pair?

like if for

```
`1.` valueMap(nickname=Antony,account=4587569854256) and 
`2.` regExMap(nickname==^(?![ ])(?=.*[\w]).{1,70}(?<!\s)$,account==^([0-9]{3,20})$ )
```

how can I do this...

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to put a key and a value in a map? That is, how to use the put(key, value) method? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: @Joni yes, when I split `.split("###")` I will  `nickname=Antony and nickname=Antony` now I want these to be in hashmap as key and value

Comment: Which is the key and which is the value?

Comment: Split will give you an array, can't you loop through the array and put in a map ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for all your comments,

this is how I have done it, hopefully people like  can give better than this

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class SplitStrings {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String value = "nickname=Antony###account=4587569854256";
        String[] arrValue = value.split("###");
        Map<String,String> valueMap= new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (String string : arrValue) {
            String[] mapPair =string.split("=");
            valueMap.put(mapPair[0], mapPair[1]);
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks to `joni`

Comment: I can just say you got it in wrong sense .. and yes you have done what I said in my comment :)

Comment: Hey Abdullah Shaikh , Sorry for taking things in wrong sense, :), your comment made me to think and find what I want, might not be the best one but still working one :) thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you got a '###' delimiter to split the string out, then what you want to do is to just construct a HashMap and map them in iteratively?

Like:

```
HashMap<String,String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
yourString = "nickname=Antony###account=4587569854256"; 
String[] value = string.split("###");
String[] keyValue = value[0].split("=");
String[] keyValue1 = value[1].split("=");
hm.put(keyValue[0],keyValue[1]);
hm.put(keyValue1[0],keyValue1[1]);
```

Is that what you're asking for?